# If there are two injection function $f: A \rightarrow B$ and $g: B \rightarrow A$. Is $f$ a bijection function?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

By not using the Cantor-Bernstein-Schroeder theorem, is that construction correct?

If $g$ is injection there must be a left inverse function $g': A \rightarrow B$ such that $g' \circ g = id_A$.

Suppose the function $g'$ is the right inverse function of $f$ so $f$ must be a surjection function.

By definition, $f$ is an injection function, by construction, it is a surjection function. So it must be a bijection function.

How to prove $g'$ is the right inverse function of $f$?

Comment: The Theorem does not require (or imply) that either $f,g$ be a bijection.  That's the beauty of it.

Comment: Yes, the fundamental question here is: is a right inverse function it must be the unique right function?

Comment: That does not make sense.  All you have assumed is that $f,g$ are injections.  That does not imply that either is a bijection (obviously).

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ have the same cardinality $f$ must be a bijection function. Because it is one to one and both sets have the same quantity of elements.

Comment: @Guilherme No, that’s false. $f(n)=2n$ is an injection $\mathbb N\to \mathbb N$ but $\mathbb N$ and $\mathbb N$ have the same number of elements.

Comment: @GuilhermeNamen  That only holds for finite sets.  That's kind of the whole point here.

Comment: I understand the problem because there are many injections functions between $A$ and $B$, which could be as many right inverses functions. So $g'$ could or not be the right inverse of $f$.

Comment: I don't believe that you understand the problem.  $f$ does not need to be a surjection, period.  It may not have a right inverse.

Answer (score 1):

No. It provides that there exists bijection between $A$ and $B$(so they have same cardinality), but **it does not provide** $f$ **or** $g$ **is bijection**.

Let $f:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N\times\mathbb N$ as $f(x)=(x,1)$, $g:\mathbb N\times\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ as $g(x,y)=2^x3^y$. Then those two are injection, but none of them are bijection.

Comment: I cannot understand. Why it is downvoted?

Answer (score 0):

It is not.

Consider $f : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ the canonical injection, and $g : \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ any injection. Obviously $f$ is not a bijection.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand, $f$ is injection by definition.

Comment: @GuilhermeNamen It was a typo, I meant bijection.